# The date format changes back to previous one after a certain number of rows in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime-format

I am using **pd.read_excel()** to load data into data frame which have 2 columns.

- 1st column is **Date_and_Time** in below format

> **12/04/2018 03:45:00**

- 2nd column contains **Pollution index values**

I converted the **Date_and_Time column's dtype to dateandtime** and then tried to separate date and time into 2 different columns namely date and time.

```
   # converted dtype to dateandtime
   df['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date and Time'])
   
   # extracting date into one column in dd-mm-yyyy format
   df['Date'] = df['Date and Time'].dt.date
   df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
   
   #extracting time in another column
   df['Time'] = df['Date and Time'].dt.time
```

But after 1100th row the date changes

- **to:  mm-dd-yyyy format**
- **from: dd-mm-yyyy format**

Any idea as what is leading to this behavior ?
I want the dates in dd-mm-yyyy format throughout the data frame.

Comment: This format `%m/%d/%y` is not `dd-mm-yyyy`..it is `mm-dd-yyyy`. Correct that in your code and then see again.

Comment: It caught my attention also but it gives the format i want which is dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: Thanks @AbhilashAwasthi 
i rewrote the code as your observation and it worked now.
Thank you

Comment: Ok can you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code's first line, the dates were getting determined in wrong fashion by `pd.to_datetime`. So it had nothing to do with datatype getting changed in 1100th row. From first row only dates were read incorrectly.

```
df['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date and Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

df['Date'] = df['Date and Time'].dt.date
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y")

df['Time'] = df['Date and Time'].dt.time
```